# Win 2003 Junction Point to Remote Unix Share

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, file-sharing, windows-server-2003

Env : Windows Server 2003 with already established shared folders over the local Domain via Windows DC and AD. 
- Linux box being used as a fileserver with the folder /files/share being R+W by all domain users, this is not a problem.

I have already transfered the files from the Windows Box to the /files/share on the Linux Box however i now want to create a junction point in order to prevent users saving to the Windows box.

I have tried the FileServer Administration on windows server 2003 however it will not allow me to junction remote servers. 
I have tried mounting the remote filesystem as a drive and proceeding that way however no joy.

Anyone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symlink similar to the symlinks in linux.  Use the following syntax...

```
mklink /d c:\share z:\files\share
```

This will create a symlink on the C drive called share that will point to your remote linux system mounted on the Z: drive.

You will most likely need to run your `cmd` command as administrator to have privileges to create the link.  This is not a junction point but should work since it doesn't have the restrictions of being local drives only.  Hope this helps.

Here's a reference to the `mklink` command usage for your reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in windows server 2003

Applies To: Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista

Comment: It will also work in Windows 7, but its unfortunate this is not supported in Windows Server 2003.  I don't know of any other way, sorry.